# show paragraph that contains a search

Tags: jquery

Ii have several paragraph in my  page, i just want to show a paragraph that contains my search
i tried with my code unsuccesfully.
(and my second problem)I Also know i shoud use a code like:

```
if(!$( "p#all_text" ).has("#searchfor").length
```

to show element if has a search result, but how can i reassume more than 20 elements in just one jquery filter?

```js
$('#searchfor').keyup(function(){
         var Parag = $('#all_text');
         var ParagText = Parag.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
         var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
         var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");    
         var newHtml = ParagText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");
         Parag.html(newHtml);
         
         if($(this).has("<span>").length)
{
$(this).parent().show()
$(this).show();  
}
    });
```

```css
#all_text span
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color:yellow;    
}
  .starthidden {
       display: none;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchfor"/>
    <p id="all_text"   class='starthidden'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
    
    
    <p id="all_text1"   class='starthidden'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
    
      <p id="all_text2"   class='starthidden'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum..</p>
      
     <p id="all_text3"  class='starthidden'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum..</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `var Parag = $('#all_text');` you only search the first paragraph.

Instead, you want to loop all the paragraphs... You can use `$('[id^=all_text]')` for that. It gets all elements which id starts with 'all_text'.

As alternative you could add a class to the elements and use a class selector. That way you don't end up with `all_text248`.

After selecting the paragraphs, you loop them with `.each()` and use the rest of your code...

```js
$('#searchfor').keyup(function() {
  var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
  $('[id^=all_text]').each(function() {
    var ParagText = $(this).text().replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>","");
    var theRegEx = new RegExp("(" + searchedText + ")", "igm");
    var newHtml = ParagText.replace(theRegEx, "<span>$1</span>");
    $(this).html(newHtml);
    $(this).show();
  });
});
```

```css
[id^=all_text] span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: yellow;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.starthidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchfor" />
<p id="all_text" class='starthidden'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>


<p id="all_text1" class='starthidden'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>

<p id="all_text2" class='starthidden'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum..</p>

<p id="all_text3" class='starthidden'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum..</p>
```

Comment: your code il very helpful, but you take just the text, so you're clearing all HTML format.
I have an example here:[link]( http://www.suale.it/prova/Help2.html ) but still have problem with html code format